# Is it possible to change volume of ring signal without volume of the wakeup alarm being changed?

Tags: settings, audio

Is it possible to change volume of ring signal without the alarm volume being changed?
It's quite annoying having to check that the wakeup alarm is on a normal volume every night before going to bed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer, no. Currently there is no way to separate volume levels of ringer and music/alarm. The only other volume that can be changed indepedently is the in-call speaker volume (which goes from 1-10), and it can only be adjusted during a call.

A workaround (lame, but works) is to choose, or record, a new ringtone that isnt very loud. This way you can leave the phone at a higher volume throughout the day and not have to make sure it is turned up before you go to bed.

The Windows Phone team is aware of this issue and it is on the list of requested features. People are asking the volume changer to be like the one used in Windows Mobile 6.5. If you'd like to add your vote to this or any other feature go here http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions